# Adding key vault scopes for azure databricks having issues

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-databricks

I am trying to automate adding Keyvault scope for Azure DataBricks service.

Tried to use example from [here](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools/blob/master/Tests/Add-DatabricksSecretScope.tests.ps1)

**Code**

```
$Region = "southindia"
$ResID = "/subscriptions/*******/resourceGroups/******/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testkv123d"
$databricsOrgId = **********


Connect-Databricks -Region $Region -DatabricksOrgId $databricsOrgId `
    -ApplicationId ************ `
    -Secret ************ -TenantId ************  -Verbose

Connect-Databricks -Region $Region -ApplicationId ************** `
            -Secret ****************** `
            -ResourceGroupName ******* `
            -SubscriptionId ****************************** `
            -WorkspaceName *********** `
            -TenantId ********** -Verbose

Add-DatabricksSecretScope -ScopeName "kvscope" -Verbose -KeyVaultResourceId $ResID
```

**Issue Details**

```
VERBOSE: POST https://southindia.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create with -1-byte payload
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error_code":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"There was an internal error handling request POST to /api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create. Please try again later."}
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\azure.databricks.cicd.tools\2.0.55\Public\Add-DatabricksSecretScope.ps1:73 char:9
+         Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Body $BodyText -Uri "$global: ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: why are you connecting 2 times?

Comment: This is a known issue with the databricks api and that powershell module. https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools/issues/43. We are waiting on databricks to update the api.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we have no way to create an Azure Key Vault-backed scopes with REST API. We just can create it in the Azure Databricks UI. In other words, If we provide key vault resource id when we call the REST API or CLI, the api cannot be processed by the backend server. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#azure-key-vault-backed-scopes)
[image]

So if you use the PowerShell module to create a secret scope, you just can create a [Databricks-backed scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#databricks-backed-scopes).

For example
1. [Create a new Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal). **Besides, please note that make the Service Principal a Contributor on your Databricks Workspace using the Access Control (IAM) blade in the Azure portal.***

2. Script

```
$region="your workspace region"
Connect-Databricks -Region $region -ApplicationId "<sp app id>" -Secret "<sp client secret>" `
            -ResourceGroupName "<  resource group name >" `
            -SubscriptionId "<subscription id>" `
            -WorkspaceName "<workspace  name>" `
            -TenantId "<your tenant id>"
$token = New-DatabricksBearerToken -LifetimeSeconds 3600 -Comment "Secret Scope Creation"
Add-DatabricksSecretScope -Bearer $token.token_value -Region $region -ScopeName "test11"  -AllUserAccess 
Get-DatabricksSecretScopes -Region $region -ScopeName "test11"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for quick response to the issue. Is there any timeline to support the feature from Powershell. This is a blocker for automation for our project

Comment: @SreeKiranNageli  Regarding the update, You can check the update via https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?category=analytics.